# g++ installed but make says g++ not found (weird)

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I encounter a very weird problem. (I have googled this but everyone says install gcc/g++) I have `g++` and `gcc` installed (up-to-date), but when I am doing `make`, it has the following error message:

```
g++ -o even_fibo.out ./src/even_fibo.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [even_fibo.out] Error 127
```

This is my simple Makefile

```
PATH = ./src/

even_fibo.out: $(PATH)even_fibo.cpp
    g++ -o even_fibo.out $(PATH)even_fibo.cpp

clean: rm even_fibo.o
```

The weird thing is that when I don't use the `PATH` variable, that is, I type `./src/` in front of the `.cpp` file, everything works fine. And if I manually use g++ to compile, it also works. But how come it says `g++ command not found` when I just used a variable?

Thank you so much!

Comment: On which operating system? If a Linux or Posix, try `which gcc` and `which g++` and `g++ -v` in a terminal! And please explain why you believe that `g++` is installed!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ubuntu 14.04. I did `which g++` and `which gcc`, and the result is /usr/bin/g++ (gcc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't call your variable `PATH`. Call it almost anything else, for example, `SRCPATH`. [The `PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) is used to find programs, so when you change it, it can't find them.